# Liferay upgrade 7.2 to register spring beans with osgi

Tags: osgi, portlet, osgi-bundle, liferay-7, spring-portlet-mvc

While I am trying to configure a spring mvc portlet with beans and bring up the deployed war on my server I get following errors

I tried all the stuff related to spring inorder to solve NameSpaceHandler issue, but I still get error related to portlet.xml, registration of beans with container
I am using spring 4.2.5-RELEASE and XML schema all I using 3.0 version for XSD inorder for it to be compliant with webapp 3.0 XSD just to be safe.

**Logs are as mentioned below**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/context]_Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-context/portlet-application-context.xml]_ [Sanitized]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:110)
2020-05-18 08:16:53.947 ERROR [fileinstall-/project_war_Path/][HotDeployImpl:232] com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.HotDeployException: Error registering servlet context listeners for project-spring-portlet-1.0.0
com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.HotDeployException: Error registering servlet context listeners for project-spring-portlet-1.0.0
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.BaseHotDeployListener.throwHotDeployException(BaseHotDeployListener.java:38)
    at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.ServletContextListenerHotDeployListener.invokeDeploy(ServletContextListenerHotDeployListener.java:40)
    at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.HotDeployImpl.doFireDeployEvent(HotDeployImpl.java:229)
    at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.HotDeployImpl.fireDeployEvent(HotDeployImpl.java:96)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.ServletContextListenerHotDeployListener.doInvokeDeploy(ServletContextListenerHotDeployListener.java:73)
    at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.ServletContextListenerHotDeployListener.invokeDeploy(ServletContextListenerHotDeployListener.java:37)
    ... 63 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/context]_Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-context/portlet-application-context.xml]_ [Sanitized]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:118)
2020-05-18 08:16:53.957 WARN  [fileinstall-/project_war_Path/][PortletLocalServiceImpl:881] Portlet with the name apiusersspring_WAR_apiusersspringportlet100 is described in portlet.xml but does not have a matching entry in liferay-portlet.xml
2020-05-18 08:16:53.958 WARN  [fileinstall-/project_war_Path/][PortletLocalServiceImpl:893] Portlet with the name apiusersspringportlet_WAR_apiusersspringportlet100 is described in liferay-portlet.xml but does not have a matching entry in portlet.xml
2020-05-18 08:16:53.958 ERROR [fileinstall-/project_war_Path/][PortletBagFactory:288] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.portlet.DispatcherPortlet cannot be found by project-spring-portlet-1.0.0_1.0.0
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.portlet.DispatcherPortlet cannot be found by project-spring-portlet-1.0.0_1.0.0
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:419)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:411)
2020-05-18 08:16:53.963 ERROR [fileinstall-/project_war_Path/][PortletBagFactory:214] javax.portlet.PortletException: java.lang.NullPointerException
javax.portlet.PortletException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.liferay.portlet.internal.InvokerPortletFactoryImpl.create(InvokerPortletFactoryImpl.java:111)
    at com.liferay.portal.monitoring.internal.portlet.MonitoringInvokerPortletFactoryImpl.create(MonitoringInvokerPortletFactoryImpl.java:115)
    at com.liferay.portlet.internal.PortletInstanceFactoryImpl.init(PortletInstanceFactoryImpl.java:275)
    at com.liferay.portlet.internal.PortletInstanceFactoryImpl.create(PortletInstanceFactoryImpl.java:181)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.liferay.portlet.internal.InvokerPortletImpl.<init>(InvokerPortletImpl.java:122)
    at com.liferay.portlet.internal.InvokerPortletFactoryImpl.create(InvokerPortletFactoryImpl.java:107)
    ... 80 more
2020-05-18 08:16:53.966 ERROR [fileinstall-/project_war_Path/][HotDeployImpl:232] com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.HotDeployException: Error registering portlets for project-spring-portlet-1.0.0
com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.HotDeployException: Error registering portlets for project-spring-portlet-1.0.0
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.BaseHotDeployListener.throwHotDeployException(BaseHotDeployListener.java:38)
    at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.PortletHotDeployListener.invokeDeploy(PortletHotDeployListener.java:99)
    at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.HotDeployImpl.doFireDeployEvent(HotDeployImpl.java:229)
    at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.HotDeployImpl.fireDeployEvent(HotDeployImpl.java:96)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.HotDeployUtil.fireDeployEvent(HotDeployUtil.java:27)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PluginContextListener.fireDeployEvent(PluginContextListener.java:189)
```